# ASP .Net MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to write a simple ASP.NET MVC application. But in the end, while adding a view into action result, I have an issue. I am attaching the code snippet of controller file and error message.

Error message is:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   There was an error getting the type ‘PracticeMVC.Models.myc, Models.DataClasses1.designer.cs.dll, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = null’. Try rebuilding the project.

What are the steps I should follow to fix this error?

Controller `DataLogicController.cs`:

```
    public ActionResult AddCustomer(int p, string q, string r)
    {
        DataLogic obj = new DataLogic();
        obj.InsertData(p, q, r);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult UpdateCustomer(int p, string q, string r)
    {
        DataLogic obj = new DataLogic();
        obj.UpdateData(p,q,r);

        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult DeleteCustomer(int p)
    {
        DataLogic obj = new DataLogic();
        obj.DeleteData(p);

        return View();
    }
```

Comment: have you tried a clean and rebuild? also make sure the website isn't running somewhere

Comment: do you mean you find this issue when you try to generate a new view

Comment: yes. this is the first view I tried to add. Instead of adding it is showing this error message.

Comment: Yes I cleaned the solution and rebuild it several times. But its not working.

Comment: remove mvc dll from reference and then Reinstalled Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc package. clean and rebuilt the solution.

Comment: I reinstalled MicrosoftAsp.Net MVC package, then clean the solution and rebuild it. Now it is working. Thank you Mannan Bahelim.

Answer (score 0):

In this case,
First, remove the mvc.dll from reference.Next reinstall the asp .net mvc package, then clean the application solution and finally build the solution and add view to the Action Results.